# Is there any way to avoid the need for absurdly simplistic WPF/XAML Converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I ran into the need for this (evidently, again) today. Fortunately I'd already coded for it:

```
public class BooleanInverterConverter : IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) 
   { 
      return !((bool)value); 
   }
    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }
}
```

I'd also noticed my own comment on it, which made me chuckle -

```
//Seriously? Kill me...
```

However, it brings up a valid point and leads me to my question - is this sort of thing absolutely necessary?

Comment: What is this for? A toggle button?

Comment: You could already invert the value via property in the model.

Comment: You should not throw `NotImplmentedException` in `ConvertBack`, according to the MSDN page on [`IValueConverter.ConvertBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback(v=vs.110).aspx) if you can not convert back you should either return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` or `Binding.DoNothing` depending on if you want stuff relying on your converter to fall back to `Binding.FallbackValue` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the boolean converter, no it is provided by the system in the controls namespace so one doesn't have to create their own converter. See

[BooleanToVisibilityConverter Class (System.Windows.Controls)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

Also if you don't want a converter...just put a property on the VM which returns visibility.

```
public Visibility ShouldTheButtonBeShown 
  { 
     get { return isValid ? Visbility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; }
  }
```

---

FYI to further make things a touch easier how about avoiding having to declare a converter as a static instance?

To accomplish that, one can create a base class for any converter which will initializes it as a singleton. That will allow one to skip having to define it on page's resource as a static instance of it.

I describe it here on my blog

[Xaml: Call Binding Converter Without Defining StaticResource in Xaml Thanks to Markup Derived Base Class in C# « OmegaMan's Musings](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1000)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not referring directly to visibility; I'm referring to like value = !value in this case, specifically; sorry if my comment was a little misleading.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will look into that as a desirable alternative to dealing with these stupid converters...

Comment: I have a bunch of such converters in a shared lib. For the simple ones, I can even avoid defining them in the resources by declaring a static `Instance` property. This way you can write something like `IsReadOnly="{Binding CanModify, Converter={x:Static shared:BooleanInverterConverter.Instance}}"`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid converters almost entirely by using triggers. I do all my XAML with triggers nowadays. Converters are a pain to work with...so I only use them when I have some semi complicated multi value logic.